# Can I exclude Outlook results from the Start Menu search in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-outlook, search, windows-search

When I use the search from the Start Menu in Windows 7, results/mail from Outlook shows up.

How can I disable this? I only want to disable showing the mails when I search from the Start Menu - I don't want to do anything that affects indexing/searching mails from within Outlook itself.

Comment: Refer to this [link](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2014/09/how-to-exclude-outlook-results-from.html).

Answer (score 4):

I think removing outlook from Windows' search index does affect searching in Outlook.

But there's a way to remove this via policies. Just write this into a .reg file and "run" it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies]
"NoSearchCommInStartMenu"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Yes, this appears to be the correct answer. Turning off indexing in Outlook does seem to disable searching within Outlook.

Comment: This is the correct key for me on windows 7: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

Answer (score 3):

Search for "Indexing options" from the start menu. Open it.

- Click `Modify`
- Untick the checkbox next to `Microsoft Office Outlook`
- Click `OK`

You should not see search results from Outlook anymore.

Note: the checkbox does not appear unless you have Outlook set as your default Mailto: / MAPI handler in "Default Programs"

[image]

Comment: And this will not affect indexing/searching mails from within outlook ?

Comment: According to my experience, no, it does not affect outlook search. Outlook 2007 has its own search/indexing options (Tools->Options->Preferences->Search Options)

Comment: Disabling indexing breaks Outlook search. [Adding this registry value](https://superuser.com/a/288467/467894) is a better option for removing results from the Start Menu specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Just a heads up, the "Indexing options" solution that someone mentioned will also disable your ability to search through your e-mail within outlook.  You'll have to turn it back on if you want to have any search capabilities without Outlook.  And what's worse, you can't simply turn back on this feature.  It needs to re-index all of your e-mail, which can take quite a while.

Comment: Is this a comment or an answer? Answer posts need to actually *attempt* to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding (without the quotes) "-type:message"

Seems to work for me in the search box in Windows Explorer.

I personally wouldn't touch the Indexing just in case it causes Outlook to reindex.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to filter-out Outlook messages from your search results (e.g. so you only see stored documents, not also any emails with those docs attached to them), try including the following in your search string:

`*from:NOT [yourname] to: NOT [yourname]`

Putting my email name in the string excludes any emails I've sent or received, leaving just a list of docs.

It's not elegant but it gets rid of all the duplicate results that Win 7 Search throws up.